# How to do a Library Override in my theme for dialog.ajax.js

Tags: 8

I’m trying to do a libraries-override to the dialog.ajax.js file appearing in /core/misc/dialog/. (Want to replace it with a js file from my theme, let's say at mytheme/js/dialog.ajax.js)

In my theme’s  *info.yml file, I tried

```
libraries-override:
  drupal.dialog.ajax:
    js:
      assets/js/dialog.ajax.js: false
```

as another post suggested (just to try and disable it). Didn't work.

My confusion comes from not knowing how to correctly target the /core/misc/dialog/dialog.ajax.js file within my override, and then correctly target my mytheme/js/dialog.ajax.js as a replacement.

I reviewed the documentation, but it's still quite unclear. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing the `core/` prefix:

```
libraries-override:
  core/drupal.dialog.ajax:
    js:
      assets/js/dialog.ajax.js: false
```

Comment: Thank you... helped point me in the right direction. Had to experiment a bit though to get the right paths. For anyone else wanting to see my final solution for this... here it is.
`libraries-override:
  core/drupal.dialog.ajax:
    js:
      misc/dialog/dialog.ajax.js: /themes/custom/THEMENAME/js/overrides/dialog.ajax.js`